# Downgrade Java 8 streams to Java 7 loops in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, refactoring, java-7

I have some code written using Java 8 features, which means streams and lambdas. Now, I have to reuse such code in a project that uses Java 7. Is there the possibility to automatically refactor the code using IntelliJ?

For example, I have to refactor some code that looks like the following, into a simple `for` / `while` loop.

```
Arrays.stream(values)
      .distinct()
      .limit(2)
      .count();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, IntelliJ has "Replace Stream API chain with loop" refactor option. It pops up after pressing `Alt+Enter` after placing cursor on the `Arrays.stream()` method:

[image]

It will produce code like:

```
long count = 0L;
long limit = 2;
Set<Integer> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>();
for (int i : new int[]{1, 2, 3}) {
    if (uniqueValues.add(i)) {
        if (limit-- == 0) break;
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

For the option to work the project language level has to be 8 or higher.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-183.5429.30, built on January 29, 2019

Comment: Is it an "Ultimate" version feature? I am using the Community Edition.

Comment: No idea, do note that in my code example you have `count()` result assigned to a variable. Otherwise there is nothing to refactor as your code has no side effect.

Comment: Yeah, that is why you are not seeing the option, unless you assign the returned value to a var it won't be there.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin For community also have that option .

Comment: Ok, I've got it. You have to ask IntelliJ the refactoring when the code is still in the project that uses Java 8. @KarolDowbecki can you update the answer with this information?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need that much of code for the current logic though(refactoring here seems not optimal and less readable to me atleast.)

What also works is simply using a `Set` and working around its size:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(values);
System.out.println(set.size() > 2 ? 2 : set.size());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am not asking to refactor the code snippet manually. I need to do it automatically using IntelliJ.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin True, but that's where the code refactoring bit sucks. It modulates your code in the way it wants. :) Hence one must give equal importance to understanding what logic you they are operating on.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't need to run unit tests on a code that automatically refactored. If I change the code manually, there is the chance that I will introduce some bug.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin well definitely unless your unit test "covers" the implementation bit...because if it does, then you shouldn't be able to introduce a bug while refactoring for sure.